# Jenkins Multibranch Job configuration as a pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have mutibranch job in jenkins. Is there any way i can do the multibranch job configurations in a Jenkinsfile? like branchsource , behaviours etc in multibranch job i want to store as a code

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is NO.

But if you still want it, you can store job xml configuration in Git, and then update job through Jenkins API using a local script or even another Jenkins job. Don't recommend though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply